# Writing a piecewise function inside deff

Tags: if-statement, plot, scilab, piecewise

I am using [**deff**](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/deff.html) to define piecewise functions in Scilab. I use if-else statements to define the function in different intervals. All of them seem to work except for [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRiih.png).

This is my approach:

```py
deff('a=f(p)', ["if(q >= -2 & q <= -1) then"; "a=1"; "elseif(q >= 1 & q <= 2) then"; "a=-1"; "else"; "a=0"; "end";])
```

The same approach worked on similar functions such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HMny.png).

```py
eff('a=f(p)', ["if((p > 0 & p <= 2)) then"; "a=p/2"; "else"; "a=0"; "end";])
```

I have defined `q` as so:

```
q = -3:Ts:3;
```

where Ts is some floating point number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you validate the answer if it is ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your function as-is when the input is a vector. A possible workaround is to use `feval`:

```
a = feval(q,f)
```

Another (better) solution is to code `f` in a vectorized manner:

```
function a = f(q)
     a = 1*(q >= -2 & q <= -1) - 1*(q >= 1 & q <= 2)
end
```

the `1*` are not necessary unless you need to change the values.